# wp_list_page with something like showpost

Tags: wp-list-pages

I'm using this code

```
    <?php
        $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
        $subpages = ($post->post_parent) ? wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0') : wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0') ; 
            if ($children) { ?>
               <li><?php echo $children; ?></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
               <?php echo $subpages; ?> 
    <?php } ?>
```

This code display child pages on a parent page, also if there are not childs it will display the child of the parent (brothers).

However I need to restrict it to display only 5 pages, something like showpost=5 for post, I havent been able to do it, any help???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass `number=5` and it should work since `wp_list_pages()` uses `get_pages()` which has number parameter, and also if you look at [wp_list_pages codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) at the bottom under change log you can see that it take the `number` parameter since version 2.8

Comment: worked great! thx a lot!